# jQuery working in Firefox, Safari but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have written some code with jquery works in firefox, safari and ie9. But chrome does not like it. No obvious msgs in chrome console coming up. I am hitting a wall hopefully someone can shed some light. Script just show/hides some tooltips. Any ideas?
fiddle here, changed code still no change to behaviour.

http://jsfiddle.net/qAfwJ/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //custom toolTip Written by CASherwood but not working in ie9/chrome
        var ShowId;
        var id;
        var contentholder = $(".contentBox");
        var toolTip = $(".info");
        var idHashString = '#info';
        var idString = 'id';

            function showToolTip(name, id){
                  id = name + id;
                  $(id).fadeIn(1000);
            }

            function hideToolTip(name, id){
                  id = name + id;
                  $(id).fadeOut(1000);
            }

        $(toolTip).mouseover(function(){
                ShowId = $(this).attr(idString);
                showToolTip(idHashString, ShowId);
        });

        $(contentholder).mouseleave(function(){
            ShowId = $(this).find('.info').attr(idString);
            hideToolTip(idHashString, ShowId);
        });


});
```

Comment: could you extract some html and post it here too?
or put it into a jsfiddle perhaps
it would help to test.

Comment: LOL - [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287979/hover-function-only-working-properly-in-chrome) is exactly the opposite :P Only works in chrome... Perhaps you two should meet up ;)

Comment: Please can you please build a demo of the problem, perhaps on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? The question does not include any markup which would help to clarify the problem

Comment: The fiddle is working OK for me in Chrome. I see tooltips when hovering over the _i_ character. I did see that you are using `id` attributes that start with numbers which is only valid for HTMl5 doctype but that shouldn't cause it to not work in Chrome. Which version of Chrome are you using? I am using 24.0.1312.5 dev-m

Comment: Hi, I am embedding this as a widget in a learning environment (blackboard) I think this is the problem. Right pain! think i need to use noConflict();

Comment: If there are multiple versions of jQuery on the page, this could definitely cause problems

Comment: so the code works in opera/ff/ie9 (to an extent) and safari. This is interesting!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things here,
You are setting a variable `var toolTip = $(".info");`

And then using this same variable to add a function to it.
What you are doing here is actually

```
$($(".info")).mouseover(
```

Instead of

```
var toolTip = $(".info");
toolTip.mouseover(
```

Also you might consider using

```
jquery.hover(handlerIn(eventObject) , handlerOut(eventObject)  );
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: `$(<jquery-object>)` is the same as `<jquery-object>`, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Actually, that's not quite right. It creates a clone of the jQuery object, but they both reference the same DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

Ok one thing I'm noticing here is that you are wrapping some elements twice with the jQuery selector.

```
var contentholder = $(".contentBox");
$(contentholder).mouseleave(function(){
  ...
});
```

Basically what evaluates to is this -

```
$($(".contentBox"))
```

That doesn't look too good and I'm not too sure if it would work as expected. Even if it does, the issues of cross browser compatibility might come into play and I believe this is what you are experiencing. If you have already captured the element and are not just storing the selectors as strings, then there is no need to wrap the element again with the `$` syntax.

```
var contentholder = $(".contentBox");
contentholder.mouseleave(function(){
  ...
});
```

When you are constructing selectors from strings and variables, you should do so in a similar way to this -

```
var elementId = 'the_elements_id';
$('#'+elementId).on('click',handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by changing

```
        $(toolTip).mouseover(function(){
                ShowId = $(this).attr(idString);
                showToolTip(idHashString, ShowId);
        });

        $(contentholder).mouseleave(function(){
            ShowId = $(this).find('.info').attr(idString);
            hideToolTip(idHashString, ShowId);
        });
```

to

```
        toolTip.mouseover(function(){
                ShowId = $(this).attr(idString);
                showToolTip(idHashString, ShowId);
        });

        contentholder.mouseleave(function(){
            ShowId = $(this).find('.info').attr(idString);
            hideToolTip(idHashString, ShowId);
        });
```

since your toolTip and contentholder variables are already jquery objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure and haven't tested it, but what if you try to move the two functions (`showToolTip()` and `hideToolTip()`) before or after the `$(function(){});` 
The might get seen as inner functions of some sort instead of global functions and that might be a thing.